# Why are no posts showing despite my apparently correct DB restoration?

Tags: database, wp-admin, mysql, backup

I restored a backup to  MySQL using the phpMyAdmin Import feature. When I browse the DB in phpMyAdmin, I see that my posts are there. But in Wordpress, I only see the default out-of-the-box welcome post.  Even the WordPress admin shows no signs of the info in the database. (I checked that this is the correct database.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are all credentials in wp-config.php right? Don't forget from table prefix.

Comment: From where did the backup originate from, the same server or another? Did you just restore a table or the complete database, are you sure WordPress is indeed using the same db/table?

Comment: @Alexey Thanks that is probably it. Please add an answer so I can award you the bounty after I confirm that this really is the source of the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check all credentials in `wp-config.php`. And don't forget about table prefix.

Comment: As you asked, Joshua :)

Comment: saved me with the table prefix, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple databases and that WordPress is not accessing the correct one.  Check your `wp-config.php` file (in the base of your WordPress installation) and make sure that your database credentials, in particular `DB_NAME`, are set correctly.

You may also need to create/grant access to a new database user.  There's about a dozen different ways of doing this, many of them are covered in the [codex page on installing WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Step_2:_Create_the_Database_and_a_User).  Pick the one that works best for you if you have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Check The Table Prefix in the wp.config file math the one in the database.  For Example Most Tables starts with wp_  cross check if your new table prefix has added numbers e.g.  wp143_

Thats All